# Expand rows with lists as observations

Tags: r

I have the following frame:

```
df <- structure(list(returns = list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10,11,12)), indexId = c("a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)
```

Is there an easy way to convert this into a normal `data.frame` so it appears as:

```
Choice ppl
   1   a
   2   a
   3   a
   4   a
   5   a
   6   a
   7   b
   8   b
   9   b
  10   b
  11   b
  12   b
```

I have a solution using `For` but I am looking for something simpler.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(returns = list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10,11,12)), 
                     indexId = c("a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% separate_rows()

#    returns indexId
# 1        1       a
# 2        2       a
# 3        3       a
# 4        4       a
# 5        5       a
# 6        6       a
# 7        7       b
# 8        8       b
# 9        9       b
# 10      10       b
# 11      11       b
# 12      12       b
```

Answer (score 3):

Or :

```
data.frame(choice = unlist(df$returns), ppl = rep(df$indexId, lapply(df$returns, length)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have quite a few different functions that will run this and all with different colnames so a tidyverse version will save quite some time!